# Why is a Chinese symbol on some of my WhatsApp contacts?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I have WhatsApp application installed on the latest version of Android on my phone.

I've noticed that for some contacts, a Chinese symbol (which I translated using Google Photos with automatic language detection and seems to mean "Telephone" in simplified Chinese) appears close to some of my contacts:

[image]

Why is that symbol appearing? I've tried to find a common pattern across these contacts but I couldn't find any: the symbol appears on contacts that I'm sure they don't have my number (but other contacts that I'm sure they don't have my number isn't showing it), and vice versa - some contacts that I am sure they have my number and still the symbol appears.

Would you have any idea of why that happens? I couldn't find any explanation on the internet and I wouldn't know where to ask if not on this forum.

Comment: Do these people live in China or speak Chinese?

Comment: @TheMovieMan, no, not at all. They all live in Europe and do not speak Chinese. I've just noticed that I have the same symbol in my list of missed calls (in the native phone app in android, just close to the date of the missed call), and for those two people I am sure they have my number saved in their contacts. Though what I know is that these 2 people have themselves an Android phone.

Comment: Cursory research returned [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-WhatsApp-display-phone-mobile-under-the-contacts-tab-Any-difference-between-them) mentioning 1) that's how the contacts are saved on the device, and 2) yes, 电话 means "Phone", so it could be possibly the default value stored. Though, WhatsApp Business v2.22.16.75 on my Pixel 3a Android 12 and WhatsApp v2.22.16.75 on my Nexus 5, Android 7.1.2 (both using Google Contacts) don't show anything that says "mobile" anywhere... so just in case, could you also mention the device model, Android version, and the default Contacts app?

Comment: @AndrewT. Well caught! Indeed I opened the contact on my phone and saw that the number was saved under this section with the Chinese symbol. The common pattern that I found across all these contacts is that they have been imported into my phone from an iPhone (I had an iPhone before switching to Android), so apparently that operation did something that those contacts now show "mobile" in Chinese!